# Inserir o resultado de uma consulta em um arquivo php

Tags: php, windows

Preciso criar um arquivo .php com os resultados que aparecem acessando outro arquivo .php, por exemplo:

Eu acesso http://localhost/arquivos.php e está página me resulta a listas de arquivos existentes numa página. Para isso eu uso este código:

```
<?php
$pasta = 'imagens/';

if(is_dir($pasta))
{
    $diretorio = dir($pasta);

    while(($arquivo = $diretorio->read()) !== false)
    {
        echo ''.$arquivo.'<br />';
    }

    $diretorio->close();
}
else
{
    echo 'A pasta não existe.';
}
```

?>

Eu preciso que o resultado "arquivo1.ini", "arquivo2.ini"... seja gravado em um arquivo .php. Tentei modificar o código da página da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
    $filename = 'meuteste.php';
    $pasta = '/xampp/htdocs/';
    if(is_dir($pasta))
    {
        $diretorio = dir($pasta);

        while(($arquivo = $diretorio->read()) !== false)
        {
        int file_put_contents ($filename, echo ''.$arquivo.'</a><br />');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'A pasta não existe.';
    }
?>
```

Mas o comando está errado, recebo esta mensagem ao abrir http://localhost/arquivos.php:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'file_put_contents' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\lista.php on line 10

Alguém já passou por algo assim? Sabe da solução?

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: remove aquele `int` antes do `file_put...`

Comment: Boa tarde rray,
sem o int, aparece o seguinte erro:

 > Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\lista.php on line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem dois erros de sintaxe nessa linha, remova o `int` e o `echo` do segundo argumento.

```
int file_put_contents ($filename, echo ''.$arquivo.'</a><br />');
-^                            -----^
```

O correto:

Também faltou especificar a forma que será gravado o arquivo, se a cada iteração do while sobrescreverá o arquivo ou adicionará ao existente, isso é feito iformando o terceiro argumento como `FILE_APPEND`

```
<?php
    $filename = 'meuteste.php';
    $pasta = '/xampp/htdocs/';
    if(is_dir($pasta)) {
        $diretorio = dir($pasta);
        while(($arquivo = $diretorio->read()) !== false) {
            file_put_contents ($filename, $arquivo. PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
```

[Manual - file_puts_content](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Boa tarde, 
Quase deu certo, o único erro é que o arquivo 'meuteste.php' está sendo criado com apenas 1 resultado.
Em vez do arquivo ser criado com o nome de todos os arquivos da pasta, está criando com o apenas 1 resultado :(

Comment: @Wesley, atualizada a resposta

Comment: Boa noite, muito obrigado.
Após a edição deu certo!